# why can I not use org.apache.commons.math3 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, apache-commons-math

I wanted just use ***org.apache.commons.math3***.analysis.solvers.PegasusSolver;
Created a Java project in ***Eclipse*** Oxygen.3A.
Extended the build-path/classpath by **commons-math3-3.6.1.jar**.
When typing the import statement until the dot after solvers, I expected to get a list of all the classes, among them *PegasusSolver*. But the list is empty.

Just typing *PegasusSolver* led a failure mark for that line.

I updated the classpath for **3.6** version instead of 3.6.1 of commons-math3 and everything **worked as expected**.

Switching back to 3.6.1 gave me the same strange behavior.

What could be the reason that 3.6 works with Eclipse, but 3.6.1?

An Apache failure?
An Eclipse failure?
A failure on my computer?

Comment: Was there any exceptions or can you explain some of the behavior? It does sound odd.

Comment: Eclipse shows several compilation failures, e.g. not finding org.apache.commons.math3.analysis.UnivariateFunction. Just substituting 3.6.1 by 3.6 solves the issue. A screenshot of the good version (3.6) you may find here: https://pasteboard.co/HmzCPXL.png

A screenshot of the failing verions (3.6.1) you may find here: https://pasteboard.co/HmzEord.png